# Is there any efficient way to get alternate solution for 'similar_text()' in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a very large database and working on a feature to find a match between 2 strings. Basically, to identify if the string in the databases matches the string I am supplying. If the string matches like 75% then I can say its a duplicate and may discard it or let the administrator know about the duplicate.

I found the `similar_text()` method in PHP for the same but, it's not an effective and efficient solution. I want a solution that is more efficient and less consumes less resource and time.

I Googled and found a solution but it's not very efficient.[levenshtein algo](http://blog.cavar.si/2011/04/how-to-implement-levenshtein-algotithm.html).

Let me add some more information.

I need to identify the matching address in the database. For example, if the user has an address `House Number 2949, west palm street, NY` and other has an address `2949, west palm st., NY` these addresses are 71% match. I want to add a feature in my program to identify the matching address if they match 75% while they are registering. We may add them as family.

Here is the algorithm I am currently checking the match with:

```
$str_1 = 'House Number 2949, west palm street, NY';
$str_2 = '2949, west palm st., NY';
$sim = similar_text($str_1, $str_2, $percentage);
echo "Sim: $sim ($percentage %)";
```

The above code returns the matching percentage in the given 2 strings in this `$percentage` variable.

I have 2 million users in the database already. So if I check it using Ajax it might take too long to process every record, can it be done using MySQL?

Can anyone help??

Comment: The task cannot have general solution, only private solution may exist. But it is highly dependent by the strings values to be compared. PS. It is possible that A is 80% to both B and C, and D is 80% to both B and C, whereas A is 65% to D and B is 65% to C...

Comment: What about full-text search with query expansion? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I just checked the full-text search with query expansion, it indeed useful to fetch a lot of records but it won't tell me what is the percentage of matching of record and also it doesn't allow me to set any specific percentage using which I can choose to fetch the records accordingly. For right now, I am using my own code with Ajax. However, it is going to take a lot of time with a huge database or it might show timeout during the operation. Its too much resource consuming. I am still positively looking for solution